# Spring ldap authenticate without lookup

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

Spring-Ldap 1.3.1

If I understand correctly, LdapContextSource has no method to set a bind-property making it necessary to perform a lookup during the authenticate method of LdapTemplate (or LookupAttemptingCallback respectively), because the provided password would not be validated otherwise.

I ran into the situation where the users to be authenticated have no rights on the directory service to perform a lookup.

The easiest solution I found was to not use LdapTemplate but instead take the set up environment

```
contextSource.getContext(username, pw).getEnvironment()
```

and use it as constructor-argument for a InitialDirContext but it seems quite as "not how it should be". So the question is, how can it be done better?

Comment: The situation is invalid. The normal usage of LDAP is that you lookup the user based on some attribute like email address, and then attempt to bind as that user with the provided password.

Comment: My point is, that for binding LdapTemplate does this:
 DirContext ctx = contextSource.getContext(userDn, pw);
 ctx.lookup();
whereas with InitialDirContext you just can use
 new InitialDirContext(env);